# Merging CSS transforms

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions

I am trying to merge a few different CSS transforms on an H3 element. The initial transform is to rotate the text -45deg, while the second set is sliding and fading the element in place.

```
h3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); // rotate text
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s, opacity 0.6s; // use when element is in view
}

// use when element is in view
.about-trans {
    h3 {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-60px);
        transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
}
```

Comment: and you wish to preserve the rotation when the element is in view? Or you want to have a sequenced animation where you do anim1, anim2 etc. in a row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to have multiple transofrmations applied just concatenate them like in the CSS below:

```
    h3 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); // rotate text
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s, opacity 0.6s; // use when element is in view
    }

    // use when element is in view
    .about-trans {
        h3 {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px) rotate(-45deg);
            -moz-transform: translateY(-60px) rotate(-45deg);
            transform: translateY(-60px) rotate(-45deg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your transform as Transform matrix. The shortest version of concatenated Transform would be, if you multiply these matrices.

That way, you would have only one transform with one matrix in each definition.